# Android: adding items to Spinner widget

Tags: android, arrays, list, spinner

All I have been having problems adding items from my main class to my `Spinner` widget, when I click the button my application goes to another class, but when I return back to the home page, the user's text which is input into the `textedit` box is not added to the `ListView`. **Below is my code**, any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
 public class MovieSearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner spinner;
    Button buttonSearch;
    ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_movie_search);
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
    }

    public void displayResults(View view) {
        EditText movieName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.userInput);
        String name = movieName.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MovieResults.class);
        intent.putExtra("movieName", name);
        startActivity(intent);
        spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
        buttonSearch = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSearch);
        if (buttonSearch.isActivated()) {
            names.add(name);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, names);
        spinner.setAdapter(adapter);


    }

    }
```

Comment: Does `buttonSearch.isActivated()` is true?

Comment: yes is is true I press the button